# Call Scalar function from c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a scalar function  in sql database which i want to to call using linq to Entity context.

Although I am aware, you can call table functions using following syntax.

```
    [DbFunction("Context", "TableFunc")]
    public virtual IQueryable<ModelEntity> TableFunc(int 
     Id)
    {
        var IdParam = new ObjectParameter("Id", typeof(int))
        {
            Value = Id
        };
        return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
            .CreateQuery<ModelEntity>(
                "Context.TableFunc(@Id)",IdParam);
    }
```

however if i use scalar function in this place.

I get an error "name parameter is not specified"

My scalar function does not have any parameters.

Update:
Scalar function call

```
   [DbFunction("Context","GetValue")]
   public virtual IQueryable<short> GetValue()
    {
        return (this as  
     IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<short>
     ("Context.GetValue()");
    }
```

Comment: Does `.CreateQuery<ModelEntity>(
                "SELECT ScalarFunc()");` do anything? (Put SELECT before your functuion name that returns the value)

Comment: The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.

Comment: Can you post the code of the scalar function?

Comment: added scalar function.also tried putting SELECT before Context.GetValue()

Comment: try `new ObjectParameter("@Id", typeof(int))`

Answer (score 0):

I just recently found the solution by looking at the GitHub [SourceCode](https://github.com/moozzyk/CodeFirstFunctions) and also from this [link](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/).
Fortunately, the method is very easy, it just was not coded with easily readable way, hence, I found I difficulties to use it properly.

```
public partial class MainDbContext : DbContext
    {
//....
  [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "IsAssignedIncludedInPickedRoles")]
    public static bool IsAssignedIncludedInPickedRoles(string pickedRoles, string assignedRoles)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

//.....
}
```

the ambiguity appeared in the obligation to use "CodeFirstDatabaseSchema" string itself where I was though it is a part from documentation to lead you using the dbContext name or the namespace including your dbContext, but none of these
the second thing is no code you have to write inside the function, you only have to create the SQL function via SqlCommand inside the seeding method and then enjoy your work

```
 var rslt = await ctx.AssignedInstitutions.Where(e => MainDbContext.IsAssignedIncludedInPickedRoles(e.Roles, "ARIOB")).ToListAsync();
```